# colour points in vector differently R

Tags: r, plot, point

there is a vector which looks like

```
c(50,-20,30,40,-70,3,9,-8,9)->h
```

there si a vector of colours I have

```
c("#ADCD00","#008B00","#00FF00","#ADCD00")->cols
```

I know that points 1-3 have the first colour, then 4 has the third colour,5 has the 2 colour and 6 to the rest have the last colour.

How can i tell R to plot the dots in these colours without hardcoding it? So that i can index in the colour vector

```
plot(h,col=cols[1])
```

obviously colours everything in the same colour

Answer (score 0):

Create a colour map vector that relates each point in `h` to the index of a colour in `cols`.

It is going to be the same length as `h`, initialise with `NA` values:

```
> cmap = rep(NA,length(h))
```

Now fill it in according to your scheme:

```
> cmap[1:3]=1
> cmap[4]=3
> cmap[5]=2
> cmap[6:length(h)]=4
> cmap
[1] 1 1 1 3 2 4 4 4 4
```

Then to plot, look up the colours via the colour map:

```
> plot(h, col=cols[cmap])
```

I'm not sure exactly where your concern about "not hardcoding it" applies, since that colour map vector I constructed has to exist somewhere, and that has to be "hardcoded" in some sense. Did you mean you **didnt** want to see:

```
> plot(h, col=c("#123456","#123456",.....etc...))
```

with the colours hardcoded into the `plot` function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `ggplot2` solution.  You might want to choose different colors so that the points differentiate more

```
h <- c(50,-20,30,40,-70,3,9,-8,9)
xaxis <- seq(1,9)
color <- c("one", "one", "one", "third", "second", "fourth", "fourth", "fourth", "fourth")
df <- data.frame(x = xaxis, y = h, color = color)
df
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=color)) +
  geom_point(size = 6, shape = 22) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ADCD00","#008B00","#00FF00","#ADCD00"), guide = FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Points Colored Individually")
```

[image]